# Finding a matrix representing a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for being unclear before. I'll just write down the question and steps I performed.

For a linear transformation $T:M_{2x2} \to M_{2x2}$: $T(A) = P^{-1}AP$,
$P = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ 
I need to find $[T]^E_E$ where E is the standard matrix base. 
$E_{i,j}$ = {$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$}, $1\leq i,j \leq 2$

I found $T_A$: 
 $P^{-1} = \frac{adj(P)}{det(P)} = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & -2 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ 
so now I have: $T_A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & -2 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right)A\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$

To find the $[T]_E^E$ I do what egreg suggested:

$T_A(E_{11}) = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & -2 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right) = 1\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right) + 2\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ 
and so fourth for $T_A(E_{12}), T_A(E_{21}), T_A(E_{22})$. 
$T_A(E_{12}) = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ 
$T_A(E_{21}) = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-2 & -4 \\
1 & 2 \end{array} \right)$ 
$T_A(E_{22}) = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$

But I cannot figure out how to write the matrix $[T]_E^E$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just consider $T(e_1), T(e_2),\dots,T(e_n)$, where $\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\}$ is the standard base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $k$th column of matrix $A$ is simply $Te_k$.

For example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, if $T(e_2)$ happens to be equal to $e_1 + 3e_3$, then the second column of $A$ will have entries $1,0,3$.

Comment: I mean for example: for a linear transformation $T:M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R})$;
I am having a problem understanding how this matrix will look like.